# Is there a way to dump all mysql databases except for system databases?

Tags: mysql, backup, dump

I use mysqldump to automatically dump all my databases to a text file and save this dump as backup. I use the --all-databases option which dumps my databases, but it also dumps system databases (information_schema, phpmyadmin, etc.) which I don't need.

Is there a way to dump all my databases with mysqldump without naming them explicitly on the command line (so that I don't have to modify the backup script every time I create a new database), but ignore all the system databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a bash script like this.  It checks the database's name before dumping it.

```
#!/bin/sh
DATABASES="$(/lighttpd/local/bin/mysql --user=user --password=pass -Bse 'show databases')"

for db in ${DATABASES[@]}
do
if [ $db == "information_schema" ]
then
continue
fi
echo ${db}-$(date +%m-%d-%y).sql.bz2 is being saved in /backup/mysql
mysqldump --user=user --password=pass $db --single-transaction -R | bzip2 -c > ${db}-$(date +%m-%d-%y).sql.bz2
done
```

Comment: Okay, but that means I have to list the system databases manually in the script. Is there a way to tell programmatically if a database was created by the system or the user?

Comment: not that I know of.  My MySQL db only came with information_schema and mysql as system databases.

Comment: and if you want to recombine all the dump files into one big dump, you might wish to just concatenate each to the other and the bzip at the end.

Answer (score 3):

A similar approach, excluding the dbs you don't want to backup:

```sh
user=''
pass=''
# Use a | as a separator
exclude_dbs='information_schema|mysql|performance_schema'

mysqldump -u "$user" -p"$pass" --databases $(mysql -u $user -p$pass -rs -e 'SHOW DATABASES;' | tail -n+1 | grep -v -E '^('$exclude_dbs')$' | tr '\n' ' ') > databases.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

Enter as **root** user and type in command line

```
for DB in $(mysql -Bse 'show databases' | grep -v information_schema); do \
   mysqldump $DB > "/$DB.sql"; \
done
```